# Mercurial - Ignoring Large files

Tags: mercurial

I know there is a way to get mercurial to ignore specific files using hgignore.

Is there a way to get it to ignore all files above a certain size?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551719/mercurial-hook-to-disallow-committing-large-binary-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately matching in .hgignore is done just by filenaming. However, nothing prevents you from writing a pre-commit hook that autocreates (appends) .hgignore files based on their size.

Answer (score 9):

Clever notion.  There's no built-in functionality for that, but you could rig up something like:

```
find -type f -size +10M > .hgignore
```

You could run that in a `precommit` hook, but you'll want to delete the lines from the previous entry.