# Mercurial - How to stop tracking modified file but keep the first version in repository

Tags: mercurial, makefile

I create the hg repository with my source tree. I want to keep the first version of some files such as `Makefile` in the repository and then hg don't see it modified even through I modified it.

Original problem is that `./configure` usually modifies the `Makefile` but I don't want the build files to committed in the repository. So I want to keep only first version of configure and `Makefile` in the repository so that everybody who clone my repository can run `./configure` by themself and not bother the repository

I tried `hg remove` or `hg forget` but those are stop tracking and also delete the files in the next revision of reporitory.

`.hgignore` doesn't do the things too.

I think of `hg revert` everytimes I run `./configure` or make but it's not efficient way.
Are there any better ways?

Answer (score 2):

Its usually good form to *not* track the `configure` script at all. There are some reasons for this:

- Its huge. I've seen code bases where the configure script and helper macro libraries were more than ten times the size of the actual code being compiled.
- When other developers make changes to configure.in(.ac), they are going to need to commit a new `configure` script. If three people do that, there's a good chance that Mercurial will require at least one of them to manually resolve a merge conflict in `configure` itself. Keep in mind, `configure` is machine generated, attempting to read it (much less resolve merge conflicts) may make your eyes bleed.

Generally, you'll offer a program in source form via two methods:

- Download of a release archive (e.g. foo-1.2.3-rc2.zip), this can contain the configure script.
- Downloading the repository directly using Mercurial. If they want to work with that, they'll need to have autoconf installed.

In the root of my repositories, I usually include a file called `autogen.sh` that runs all of the steps needed (`aclocal`, `autoconf`, ...), which also handles alerting the user if they need something installed. I.e. `Could not find tool aclocal, please install the autoconf package.`

Its really best to just go with the `autogen.sh` method. This means only tracking configure.in (or configure.ac) and the associated Makefiles (from Makefile.in). Let each build configure their own, and provide a `distclean` target to remove all files `configure` generates. Finally, provide a `maintainer-clean` target to remove anything that the configuration suite itself generated, e.g. `configure`.

That should help  make nightly builds easy.

Comment: Tim's dead right.  Don't keep in the repo anything that can be automatically generated, and if you do (for backup?), keep them in a separate directory where they won't be picked up / run in normal usage.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and setup a pre-commit hook which would always restore the original Makefile content if found in the changeset.
The [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551719/mercurial-hook-to-disallow-committing-large-binary-files) illustrates reading the content of the changeset to be committed.

Make sure to [use the pre-commit hook](http://www.lildude.co.uk/mercurial-precommit-isnt-entirely-pre/), and [not precommit](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html).