# setting maximum checkin size for mercurial hg?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, large-files

i'm trying to enforce the use of the [largefiles](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LargefilesExtension) extension for my project.   unfortunatly, some people don't turn on the extension or for other reasons still checkin big files to the repository directly.   thus after only a few months my repository is already 1.5gb

to force largefiles, i think if i could prevent big check deltas (via a hard-error) that should solve this problem.

I looked through the mercurial docs, and doesn't seem like this is possible to configure in the settings.    any suggestions?

Comment: It looks very similar to this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551719/mercurial-hook-to-disallow-committing-large-binary-files

Comment: indeed it is!  (same problem, different solution) 

if you would have posted this as an answer, i would accept it ;)