# Ignore 'files exceeded a filesize limit' in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to ignore 'files exceeded a filesize limit' in mercurial? Everytime I add a PDF, the push becomes very long in my project and I can't remove the file completely from the repository. [Is there a way to remove the history for a single file in Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029480/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-history-for-a-single-file-in-mercurial)

Comment: What about just adding *.pdf to your ignore filter list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2114702/218597), it gives you an idea for a solution... to write a pre-commit hook to check the filesize.